# Show $f(x,y)=x^2 y$ is differentiable on $(1,-1)$ using definition of derivative, find tangent plane

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

How to show that the function $f(x,y)=x^2 y$ is differentiable at $(1,-1)$ by using the defintion and also find the tangent plane for the surface $z=f(x,y)$ at $(1,-1)$

Comment: What is your notion of differentiability?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by notion of differentiability.

Comment: What definition do you have for differentiability? There are equivalent ways to say a multivariate function is differentiable but I don't want to use a definition you are unfamiliar with to solve the problem.

Comment: I can solve it directly but I do not know how I can solve it by using the definition

Comment: Define "directly".

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $(1,-1)$ we have to investigate the difference $f(1+X,-1+Y)-f(1,-1)$ in terms of the increment variables $X:=x-1$ and $Y:=y-(-1)$. Computation gives
$$\eqalign{f(1+X,-1+Y)-f(1,-1)&=(1+X)^2(-1+Y)-(-1) \cr
&=-2X+Y +2XY-X^2+X^2 Y \cr
&=-2X+Y + r(X,Y)\ ,\cr}$$
where $r(X,Y):=2XY-X^2+X^2Y$ satisfies $$\bigl|r(X,Y)\bigr|\leq 4 R^2\qquad(R:=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}\leq 1)\ ,$$
so that
$$\lim_{R\to 0}{r(X,Y)\over R}=0\ .$$
It follows that $f$ is differentiable at $(1,-1)$ and that
$$df(1,-1).(X,Y)=-2X+Y\ .\tag{1}$$
On the right side we see the linear approximation of $f(1+X,-1+Y)-f(1,-1)$ in terms of the increment variables $X$ and $Y$. Replacing $X$ and $Y$ by $x-1$ and $y+1$ we find the following representation of the tangent plane at $\bigl(1,-1,f(1,-1)\bigr)=(1,-1,-1)$ as a graph:
$$z=-1-2(x-1)+(y+1)=-2x+y+2\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) = \lim_{(x,y_{0})\rightarrow (x_{0},y_{0})}\frac{f(x,y_{0}) - f(x_{0},y_{0})}{x-x_{0}}$ which is made easier in this case if we first substitute throughout that $y_{0}=-1$ and $x_{0}=1$.

$\lim_{(x,-1)\rightarrow (1,-1)} \frac{f(x,-1)-f(1,-1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^{2}-1}{x-1}$.

Now that this is reduced to a 1-variable limit, you should be able to compute.

Comment: What?${{{{}}}}$

Comment: The first equation is the definition of the partial derivative with respect to $x$ at a point $(x_{0},y_{0})$.  Substitute the values, turns into a 1-variable limit.  Repeat the basic process for the derivative with respect to $y$.  Use these to form the equation of the tangent plane.

Comment: It's not the definition of $\dfrac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}$, you have a typo in the limit point.

Comment: Are you just concerned about using the del symbol?  I don't think there's risk of confusion.

Comment: My first comment as as it was because I didn't read the whole question (so I didn't realise what you wanted partial derivatives for) and because I couldn't even identify what you wrote as a partial derivative because you have $(x,y_0)\to (\color{red}x,y_0)$ instead of $(x,y_0)\to (x_0,y_0)$

Comment: Ah, I see.  Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming we are using [this definition of differential of a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_total_derivative_as_a_linear_map).

So the problem is, what can be the candidate linear function required in the definition above?

First of all it is necessary, but not sufficient, that the partial derivatives of the function exist. However, if these partial derivatives exist and are continuous, then $f$ is differentiable and its differential at any point is the linear map determined by the Jacobian matrix of partial derivatives at that point.

For a proof of this fact see [here](http://math.berkeley.edu/~sean/H53/Continuously_Differentiable.pdf) for example.

And for the tangent plane, you can view such plane as the **plane which best approximate the function in a neighborhood of a fixed point**, and then recalling the fact that a plane can be defined as the image of a linear map, and that the differential is linear you should know how to find the solution. So in fact the existence of the derivative implies the existence of the tangent plane. To compute it explicitly calculate the partial derivative in the required point, and then compute a vector normal to both of them. Let $(n_1,n_2)$ such vector, and $(P_1,P_2)$ your point the equation of the tangent plane is $$(x-P_1)n_1+(y-P_2)n_2=0$$
NB it is a general fact that a plane can be written in this way.